# Phalcon ORM Batch Update

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-orm

Simple Questions, if you Phalcon users .. you know what i want trying to do.

```
$trueFind = ProductOrderTransaction::find(["conditions"=>"protPthdId = ".$id]);
$trueFind->setTransaction($transaction); 
$trueFind->protMomsId = $monitId;
$trueFind->protMomsName = $monitName;
if (!$trueFind->update()) {
    foreach ($trueFind->getMessages() as $message) {
        $this->flash->error($message);
        $transaction->rollback($message->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I just want to do this query in orm Phalcon :

```
UPDATE product_order_transaction set protMomsId = '$monitId' , protMomsName = '$monitName' WHERE protPthdId='$id'
```

fail -> rollback.. success -> commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$items = ProductOrderTransaction::find([
    'conditions' => 'protPthdId = :id:',
    'bind' => ['id' => $id]
]);

foreach($items as $item){
    $this->db->begin();

    $item->protMomsId = $monitId;
    $item->protMomsName = $monitName;
    $update = $item->update();

    if(!$update){
        $this->db->rollback();
        continue;
    }
    $this->db->commit();
}
```